# Customize React bootstrap Carousel Indicator active class

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react bootstrap Carousel in my react js code. I am successfully able to customize react bootstrap Carousel indicators. By using below code..

```
div.crausal ol li{
height: 0.3em;
width: 4em;

background-color: #E77728 !important;
}
```

But I am not able to change the color of active class for indicator. I have tried this

```
 div.crausal ol li.active{
      background-color: blue !important;
 }
```

But it does not work.

This is my carousel class.

```
 <Carousel className={css_class.crausal}  touch={true} controls={false}>

      // Carousel items goes here //

 </Carousel>
```

I want to change the color of active class indicator.
If someone can give better carousel option other than react bootstrap to solve this issue that will also do

Answer (score 0):

I found a kind of fix after researching longer. What you can do is add normal bootstrap file in your project, import it in your component file and now react bootstrap classes are overridden by this normal bootstrap import. After that you can customize the normal bootstrap file downloaded in your project (bootstrap.min.css). But this is just a fix.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

```
div.carousel-indicators .active{
       background-color: #E77728 !important;
    }
```